# Use ternary operator to print different types in a single line

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2013

I want to avoid having code like this:

```
int x = ...;
cout << "x=";
if(x)
  cout << x;
else
  cout << "???";
cout<<"!";
```

I really want something like:

```
cout << "x=" << (x ? x : "???") << "!";
```

But this doesn't compile as `x` and `"???"` are incompatible/different types.

Is there a way to do this neatly?

Comment: is `cout << "x=" << (x ? to_string(x) : "???") << "!";` neatly ?

Comment: What's `to_string()`, I never heard of that?

Comment: [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string)

Comment: Ah, a new C++11 feature. That might be all I needed :)

Comment: The second and third operand of the ternary operator have to have one convertible to the type of the other, there is no getting around that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place `cout` in the ternary operator :

```
cout << "x="; 
(x ? cout << x : cout << "???") << "!";
```

Or use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) if your compiler supports C++ 11 :

```
cout << "x=" << (x ? std::to_string(x) : "???") << "!";
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d82b1aeca76bf7ca)

Comment: and use Boost's lexical_cast if you don't have to_string.